# Nodejs CPU spikes caused by the BytecodeHandler in v8

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, perf

I am currently working on a proxy server project and I have been using `net` and `dgram` libraries for my TCP and UDP connections. After running my server for 24 hours, I am experiencing CPU spikes to 100%.

I have been running node with `--perf_basic_prof` and I have collected the following data, this is what the CPUs were doing before the application has been restarted by myself.

```
2de2e67675a0 30 Builtin:ThrowWasmTrapFuncSigMismatch
2de2e6767640 26 Builtin:NumberFormatPrototypeFormatToParts
2de2e67676e0 20 BytecodeHandler:Wide
2de2e6767760 20 BytecodeHandler:ExtraWide
2de2e67677e0 44 BytecodeHandler:LdaZero
2de2e67678a0 48 BytecodeHandler:LdaSmi
2de2e6767960 4c BytecodeHandler:LdaUndefined
2de2e6767a20 4c BytecodeHandler:LdaNull
2de2e6767ae0 4c BytecodeHandler:LdaTheHole
2de2e6767ba0 1c BytecodeHandler:LdaTrue
2de2e6767c20 1c BytecodeHandler:LdaFalse
2de2e6767ca0 4c BytecodeHandler:LdaConstant
2de2e6767d60 f34 BytecodeHandler:LdaGlobal
2de2e6768d00 e8c BytecodeHandler:LdaGlobalInsideTypeof
2de2e6769c00 ab BytecodeHandler:StaGlobalSloppy
2de2e6769d20 ab BytecodeHandler:StaGlobalStrict
2de2e6769e40 2c BytecodeHandler:PushContext
2de2e6769ee0 28 BytecodeHandler:PopContext
2de2e6769f80 80 BytecodeHandler:LdaContextSlot
2de2e6769f80 80 BytecodeHandler:LdaImmutableContextSlot
2de2e676a060 50 BytecodeHandler:LdaCurrentContextSlot
2de2e676a060 50 BytecodeHandler:LdaImmutableCurrentContextSlot
2de2e676a120 94 BytecodeHandler:StaContextSlot
2de2e676a220 64 BytecodeHandler:StaCurrentContextSlot
2de2e676a300 87 BytecodeHandler:LdaLookupSlot
2de2e676a400 f3 BytecodeHandler:LdaLookupContextSlot
2de2e676a560 f60 BytecodeHandler:LdaLookupGlobalSlot
2de2e676b520 87 BytecodeHandler:LdaLookupSlotInsideTypeof
2de2e676b620 f3 BytecodeHandler:LdaLookupContextSlotInsideTypeof
2de2e676b780 f20 BytecodeHandler:LdaLookupGlobalSlotInsideTypeof
2de2e676c700 fb BytecodeHandler:StaLookupSlot
2de2e676c860 24 BytecodeHandler:Ldar
2de2e676c900 24 BytecodeHandler:Star
2de2e676c9a0 30 BytecodeHandler:Mov
2de2e676ca40 c3f BytecodeHandler:LdaNamedProperty
2de2e676d6e0 bf BytecodeHandler:LdaKeyedProperty
2de2e676d800 80 BytecodeHandler:LdaModuleVariable
2de2e676d8e0 117 BytecodeHandler:StaModuleVariable
2de2e676da60 ab BytecodeHandler:StaNamedPropertySloppy
2de2e676db80 ab BytecodeHandler:StaNamedPropertyStrict
2de2e676dca0 ab BytecodeHandler:StaNamedOwnProperty
2de2e676ddc0 a7 BytecodeHandler:StaKeyedPropertySloppy
2de2e676dee0 a7 BytecodeHandler:StaKeyedPropertyStrict
2de2e676e000 c3 BytecodeHandler:StaDataPropertyInLiteral
2de2e676e140 9f BytecodeHandler:CollectTypeProfile
2de2e676e240 3a0 BytecodeHandler:Add
2de2e676e640 3fc BytecodeHandler:Sub
2de2e676eaa0 454 BytecodeHandler:Mul
2de2e676ef60 428 BytecodeHandler:Div
2de2e676f400 428 BytecodeHandler:Mod
2de2e676f8a0 308 BytecodeHandler:BitwiseOr
2de2e676fc20 308 BytecodeHandler:BitwiseXor
2de2e676ffa0 308 BytecodeHandler:BitwiseAnd
2de2e6770320 314 BytecodeHandler:ShiftLeft
2de2e67706a0 314 BytecodeHandler:ShiftRight
2de2e6770a20 3f8 BytecodeHandler:ShiftRightLogical
2de2e6770e80 2f0 BytecodeHandler:AddSmi
2de2e67711e0 340 BytecodeHandler:SubSmi
2de2e6771580 370 BytecodeHandler:MulSmi
2de2e6771960 398 BytecodeHandler:DivSmi
2de2e6771d60 354 BytecodeHandler:ModSmi
2de2e6772120 1c8 BytecodeHandler:BitwiseOrSmi
2de2e6772360 1c8 BytecodeHandler:BitwiseXorSmi
2de2e67725a0 1c8 BytecodeHandler:BitwiseAndSmi
2de2e67727e0 1cc BytecodeHandler:ShiftLeftSmi
2de2e6772a20 1cc BytecodeHandler:ShiftRightSmi
2de2e6772c60 2a4 BytecodeHandler:ShiftRightLogicalSmi
2de2e6772f80 264 BytecodeHandler:Inc
```

Other than understanding that these are builtin V8 bytecode handler functions, I have no clue on how to debug the cause of my CPU spikes.

Would appreciate any help at all

Comment: you can blame `bytecodehandler` - but the bytecode it is handling is your "compiled" javascript - so, the root cause is your code

Comment: Surely the problem is in the code that I am developing. I am asking if there is any way to identify the cause of my CPU spikes. Since the code works fine without spikes for around 24 hours. Or maybe there is a better way to profile nodejs on runtime with some other tool where it would give more detailed stack analysis

Comment: @KorayGocmen: We're currently facing a rather similar issue, have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: @eol yes I did, but the problem had nothing to do with the dgram or net libraries. We had another monitoring tool running on the same box and that was causing the spikes. same question with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121648/nodejs-cpu-spikes-to-100-one-cpu-at-a-time